# Run com+ application when no user is logged into server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a com+ application that runs (initializes) through a web application. I have deployed it successfully on win XP (for testing) and on the Win Server 2008 but it only works when a user is logged-in.

Since the server is hosted on an external location (GoDaddy in my case), I cannot just log in and leave the server with user locked-in.

I tried couple of solutions that I have found on google but none worked. One of the solution was to start the COM application through a scheduled task to run when windows starts but it doesn't work. When I log back in and run the web application, a second instance of the COM application is created with the same user.

Another solution was to change the DCOM config settings - Changed to specific (admin) user from Interactive user in the Identity tab of the COM application properties. But in this case the application didn't even work. (It initialized but failed to perform any calculation).

Is there anything else that I could try? (Also tried to create a Windows service but didn't find any clear instructions anywhere..)

TK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue myself.

Just in case if anyone has a similar issue then you can do this:
- Go to users list in Control Panel and enable the option for the user you want to log in automatically when server restarts. (you will have to enter the password when you enable this option)
- Restart the server machine

The above steps should automatically log-in the user whenever the server restarts.

The only caution here is that if you remote access the server with the same credentials as the logged-in user then when you close the connection, the user is logged-off again so every time you remote access, restart the server.

Comment: I have the same issue, but couldn't follow your steps to solve the problem. In the control panel (Windows Server Datacenter 64Bit), I can manage another account but can't change anything interesting (only password, picture etc.). How can I enable that auto-login feature you are talking about?

Comment: I'd point out, there is a command that allow you to disconnect from a session, but allow it to remain active on the console, thus removing your need to reboot a server. see: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=302801
Run the following as separate commands in a batch file, as indicated by the quotes.
"tscon 0 /dest:console"
"tscon 1 /dest:console"
"tscon 2 /dest:console"